# PHP send updated POST request to external server and visit page

Tags: php, post, payment-processing

I am using the Cashflows online payment system, and am trying to submit a dynamically generated price to their server, based on a form on a webpage. However, inside the POST request that I need to send to the Cashflows terminal, I need to include an input field with a hash key. My problem is that the hash is based on a secret key, and this key is generated with one of the parameters being the price (see below), as the [integration guide](http://www.cashflows.com/support/kb/payment_page_integration_guide.pdf) suggests.

How can I submit the form with the POST parameters below to the portal using PHP?

**PHP:**

```
<?php

    $secret_key = 'foobar';
    $store_id = $_POST['store_id'];
    $cart_id = $_POST['cart_id'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $currency = $_POST['currency'];
    $test = $_POST['test'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    echo $check = hash('sha256', $secret_key . ':' . $store_id . ':' . $cart_id . ':' . $amount . ':' . $currency . ':' . $test . ':' . $description);
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $carriage_amount = $_POST['carriage_amount'];
    $postage_and_packaging = $_POST['postage_and_packaging'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

?>
```

**Form with dynamically generated price, a modified version of their [integration example](http://www.cashflows.com/support/index.php?page=developers&sub=hosted_payment_page&subsub=hosted_payment_page_examples):**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="5939523" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_id" value="captubes" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Fruush" />
    <input type="hidden" name="check" value="SOME KEY HERE" />

    <script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">

        // The next two functions round numbers to numerical formatting. They do not need to be altered when adding or removing products.
        function roundOff2(value, precision) {
            return places(value,1,precision);
        }

        function places(X, M, N) {
            var T, S=new String(Math.round(X*Number("1e"+N)))
            while (S.length<M+N) S='0'+S
            var y = S.substr(0, T=(S.length-N));
            if(N>0) 
            {
                y += '.' + S.substr(T, N);
            }

            return y;
        }

        // This function checks for empty quantities. It does not need to be altered when adding or removing products.
        function CheckNull2(value) {
            if (value == "") {
                value = "0";
            }

            return value;
        }

        // This function defines the postage and packaging location. It does not need to be altered when adding or removing products.
        function typeOfCarriage(x,whereabouts) {
            x.carriage_amount.value = whereabouts;
        }

        // This function addeds the postage and packaging to the total price of the products. Add new postage rates here, and also edit further down the page to add them to the table.
        function calculate(x) {

            basicprice = calc(x);

            if( Number(basicprice) > 0 ) {

                var postage_and_packaging = 0;

                switch (x.carriage_amount.value) {
                    case "uk" :
                        postage_and_packaging = 1.99;
                        break;
                    case "europe" :
                        postage_and_packaging = 2.99;
                        break;
                    default :
                        postage_and_packaging = 4.99;
                        break;
                }

                x.amount.value = Number(basicprice) + postage_and_packaging;

            } else {

                x.amount.value = "0";

            }

            x.amount.value = roundOff2(x.amount.value,2);

        }

        // The standard price, exluding postage and packaging is calculated here. It does not need to be altered when adding or removing products.
        function calc(x) {

            var b = Number(CheckNull2(x.price.value));
            var c = Number(CheckNull2(x.qty.value));
            var a = (b * c);

            return a;

        }

    </script>

    <p>
        <h3>Number of caps</h3>
        Tube of 6 caps: &pound;4.99 - Quantity: <input name="price" value="4.99" type="hidden" /><input name="qty" size="3" value="1" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <h3>Postage &amp; Packaging:</h3>
        <input name="carriage_amount" value="uk" type="hidden">
        <input checked="checked" name="postage_and_packaging" onClick="typeOfCarriage(this.form,'uk');calculate(this.form)" value="" type="radio" />UK (&pound;1.99)
        <input name="postage_and_packaging" onClick="typeOfCarriage(this.form,'europe');calculate(this.form)" value="" type="radio" />Europe(&pound;2.99)
        <input name="postage_and_packaging" onClick="typeOfCarriage(this.form,'world');calculate(this.form)" value="" type="radio" />Rest of World (&pound;4.99)
    </p>

    <p>
        <h3>Your Details (you will get a chance to change these):</h3>
        <span style="width: 100px; float: left;">Name:</span> <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        <span style="width: 100px; float: left;">Address:</span> <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
        <span style="width: 100px; float: left;">Postcode:</span> <input type="text" name="postcode" /><br />
        <span style="width: 100px; float: left;">Country:</span> <input type="text" name="country" /><br />
        <span style="width: 100px; float: left;">Telephone:</span> <input type="text" name="tel" /><br />
        <span style="width: 100px; float: left;">Email:</span> <input type="text" name="email" />
    </p>

    <input name="calcButton" onClick="calculate(this.form)" value="Calculate Total" type="button"> Total: &pound; <input type="text" name="amount" value="6.98" />
    <input value="Checkout" onClick="calculate(this.form)" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You need to send it to there server, not to yours.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do - I first need to send it through  my server though, so that I can generate the hash from a private/protected key

Comment: Then why there is in your code `<form action="submit.php" method="POST">` there must stand the url of the providers gateway. The standard procedure of a payment module is that you generate the code, then generate the form with hidden fields and then send it trough to the payment gateway.

Comment: Because the hash code needs to be generated dynamically according to the user's selection. I'm sending it first to my server, so that the correct code can be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the answer was relatively straightforward - I couldn't find a no-JavaScript solution, so instead of calculating everything client-side, I used AJAX to pull in a form with a correctly generated hash.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is post the form to a PHP page on your server, generate the hash, and then post it to the page that will receive it.  You can do all of that with fsockopen() or cURL and there are a ton of examples out there on how to use those.

Definitely do not store that variable as a hidden field on the form because it can be read, intercepted, and manipulated and cause a headache later for your ecommerce system.

Comment: I read up about cURL and fsockopen(), but I was under the impression that these do not redirect the user to the page that they're posting to - the user still needs to visit the Cashflows portal to receive the payment. I doubt put the feedback into an iframe will work.

Comment: Thats why you need to send it with an hash to the payment provider. Dont get me wrong, but there is nothing wrong to use hidden field for a payment request to an providers gateway. It even so that a lot of providers block certain methods like cURL. I whould stick by the examples given in the provides documentation.

Comment: Funnily enough, this is based on their documentation!

Comment: They just give examples with hidden fields. There is not an word on cURL in that documentation.

Comment: Nice job editing your “don’t lie” comment.  If you’re going to contribute be helpful and not condescending to the guy asking a question.  You definitely want to make sure you’re attacking the right guy because *I* was the one who brought up cURL and I never said it was in the documentation.

Comment: He said he wanted to generate the token server-side after the postback so I was giving him an option on how to do that.  It can be server-side if he wants to implement it that way and it’s more secure than writing any parameter to the page because there is less chance of the value being corrupted or changed.  He may also have a good business reason for wanting to do it that way – like dynamically calculating the pricing like his question suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can POST to your page that will generate the key and send user another form with hidden fields that will automatically submit to cashflow once the page loads. Here's an example of that form:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_form()
{
    document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="submit_form();">
    <form method="POST" name="myform" action="http://www.google.com/">
        <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="value1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="value2"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the user has got JavaScript disabled? I thought of this too, but surely this is a process that should all be done on the backend?

Comment: The thing is, you need to send user to external url with POST request. You can't do that with PHP. This is the way. To counter no-JS you simply require it on previous step (when user presses "buy" button) or simply add `<input type="submit" value="Press to continue"/>` to that form